# Access to a property value with an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm on an event `.change()` with jQuery.

I have `$(this)` and the `console.log($(this))` show me :

[image]

So, I need to retrieve the value `property value`. In my example, I need to retrieve `"7 Rue de Rivoli, Paris, France"`.

How can I do that?

Edit : With .val(), i have just the first property value "7 rue"

Comment: did you try expanding some of those nodes in your console to see what the structure looks like? might help you out.

Comment: Looks like `$(this).val()` is what you want.

Comment: or even `this.value`.

Comment: I have edit my post, with .val, i retrieve only the first property value, so "7 rue". I need the second, on the line "0"

Comment: We need a bit more to go on. You said you get "only the first property value" but what other values are there?  Have you split the address across elements? Can you post some HTML to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).val()` should do the trick.

Comment: no, with .val() i have juste the first property value : "7 rue"